# Month swaps to Day, Day swaps to Month when loading View asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**when user input date from date picker it is swap day and month **

```
 <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date-picker" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: It is work by use Class and Services

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.